# How to do Custom Switch exactly like UISwitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, uiswitch

I'm trying to do make Custom switch exactly like `UISwitch`. Which can toggled, on press the button or by drag the button. Please suggest me an idea.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=switch Check these libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a custom switch using bezier path.

[image]

Subclass a UIView and in the drawRect method, use this method.

This is a simple switch drawn using bezier path:

```
- (void)drawSwitch: (CGRect)frame thumbPos: (CGFloat)thumbPos
{
    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* yesColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.237 green: 0.811 blue: 0.624 alpha: 1];
    UIColor* noColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.8 green: 0.32 blue: 0.32 alpha: 1];

    //// Variable Declarations
    UIColor* switchColor = thumbPos > 20 ? yesColor : noColor;

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:yourRect cornerRadius: 20];
    [switchColor setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];


    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(thumbPos, 2.5, 35, 35)];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
}
```

The thumbpos is the position of the the white circle in the switch. you can change this on swipe gesture and animate the switch by changing this value.

The switch color will be changed base don the thumbPos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two images same as UISwitch and change set image while tap on UIbutton.

Comment: Then how can I will drag?

Comment: UIButton is a subclass of UIView so you can use UIView.animateWithDuration with a button. For example you can say something like:    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                    sender.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion:{(finished) in
                    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: arrItems[intItemCounter]), forState: .Normal)
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,animations:{
                    sender.alpha = 1.0
                    },completion:nil)
             })

        }

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button and set image for states.
You have to set image for two states ->
 1: selected state
 2: default state

And change state in the action method of this button.

Comment: Is it possible to move button along with finger swipe to Off or On state

Comment: You have to add swipe/tap gesture and change state in the action of swipe gesture method.

Comment: I need to show the movement along with swipe. In swipe Gesture its not possible